# Can i get the text from android calculator and set it to a edit text of app

Tags: android, calculator

If i have a button in activity to open the calculator that came with phone can i get the text from calculator and set it to edit text in activity, or do i have to build my own calculator to do this.

Comment: If it is possible, I think it is a security problem (one app copying text from another app) and may be used to steal valuable user information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the stock calculator is not set up to allow that.

If you want that functionalit you'd have to build your own Calculator Activity in such a way that it returns a result, then you could use startActivityForResult() from your first activity.